# Can a Scala case object be used in a match case

Tags: scala

Can a Scala case object be used in a match case?

E.g. this does *not* work:

```
abstract class A
case object B extends A

object something {
  val b = B
  b match { case _:B => println("success") }
}

not found: type B
b match { case _:B => println("success") }
                 ^
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oops, seems that this also compiles:

```
abstract class A
case object B extends A

object something {
  val b = B
  b match { case B => println("success") }
}
```

Scala Fiddle: [Can a Scala case object be used in a match case](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/uj386Ao/1)

Comment: @pme are you sure? haven't touched Scala in a while

Comment: @matanster yep - pretty much. I added a Scala Fiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/uj386Ao/2

Answer (score 21):

You need to specify `B.type`:

```
object something {
  val b = B
  b match { case _:B.type => println("success") }
}
```